# Value of variable for every single iteration

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Arrays_0

Implicit none

Integer :: i , Read_number , Vig_Position , Vipg_Position , n_iter
Integer , parameter :: Br_gra = 12
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vig = [ ( i , i = 1 , Br_gra) ]
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vipg = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 7 , 7 , 7 ]
Integer :: Result_of_calculation

Write(*,*)"Enter the number (From 1 to Br_gra):"
Read(*,*) Read_number

Vig_Position = Vig(Read_number)
Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

   n_iter = 0

   Result_of_calculation = Vig_Position

   Do while( Vipg_Position .ne. Vipg(1) )

      n_iter = n_iter + 1

      Vig_Position = Vipg_Position

      Result_of_calculation = Result_of_calculation + Vig_Position

      Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

   End Do

Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The number of iteration is:",n_iter
Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The result of calculation is:",Result_of_calculation

End Program Arrays_0
```

Intention is to get value in every iteration for a variables:
`Vig_Position , Result_of_calculation and Vipg_position`.
How to declare variables for that kind of calculation?
In general, is there other method for counting a number of iteration?
How to declare variables in function of number of iteration befoure the code set that number like result of calculation?

Comment: declare an array sufficiently large to hold an expected number of iterations

Comment: There is no "expected number of iteration". That number is unknown at the start of program.

Comment: you don't need to know the number, only an upper bound. If the number of iterations is potentially taxing the memory of the computer you should elaborate in the question.

Comment: Can you write suggestion for this code?

Comment: `real::saveresult(10000) `...`saveresult(n_iter)=Result_of_calculation`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it that you would like to change this program so that all of the values of Vig_position, Result_of_calculation and Vipg_Position are stored so that you can see all of them after the loop exits? There is no simple way to do that unless you know an upper bound for the count and declare a fixed array of that size. Otherwise you have to start out with an allocatable array of some size and if that becomes too small, extend the size by reallocating and copying.

Comment: Yes. Exactly that is what i want. I want to compare results of calculation from every single iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the question has been clarified, here's a typical way of solving the problem in Fortran. It isn't the only possible way, but it is the most general. The strategy in routine resize to double the old size is reasonable - you want to minimize the number of times this is called. The data set in the sample program is small, so to show the effect I allocated the array very small to begin with. In reality, you would want a reasonably large initial allocation (say, 100 at least).

Note the use of an internal procedure that inherits the type vals_t from its host.

```
Program Arrays_0

Implicit none

Integer :: i , Read_number , Vig_Position , Vipg_Position , n_iter
Integer , parameter :: Br_gra = 12
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vig = [ ( i , i = 1 , Br_gra) ]
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vipg = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 7 , 7 , 7 ]
Integer :: Result_of_calculation

! Declare a type that will hold one iteration's values
type vals_t
    integer Vig_Position
    integer Vipg_Position
    integer Result_of_calculation
end type vals_t
! Declare an allocatable array to hold the values
! Initial size doesn't matter, but should be close
! to a lower limit of possible sizes
type(vals_t), allocatable :: vals(:)
allocate (vals(2))

Write(*,*)"Enter the number (From 1 to Br_gra):"
Read(*,*) Read_number

Vig_Position = Vig(Read_number)
Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

   n_iter = 0

   Result_of_calculation = Vig_Position

   Do while( Vipg_Position .ne. Vipg(1) )

      n_iter = n_iter + 1

      Vig_Position = Vipg_Position

      Result_of_calculation = Result_of_calculation + Vig_Position

      Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

      ! Do we need to make vals bigger?
      if (n_iter > size(vals)) call resize(vals)
      vals(n_iter) = vals_t(Vig_Position,Vipg_Position,Result_of_calculation)

   End Do

Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The number of iteration is:",n_iter
Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The result of calculation is:",Result_of_calculation

! Now vals is an array of size(vals) of the sets of values
! For demonstration, print the size of the array and the values
Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"Size of vals is:", size(vals)
Write(*,'(3i7)') vals(1:n_iter)

    contains
    ! Subroutine resize reallocates the array passed to it
    ! with double the current size, copies the old data to
    ! the new array, and transfers the allocation to the
    ! input array
    subroutine resize(old_array)
    type(vals_t), allocatable, intent(inout) :: old_array(:)
    type(vals_t), allocatable :: new_array(:)

    ! Allocate a new array at double the size
    allocate (new_array(2*size(old_array)))
    write (*,*) "Allocated new array of size ", size(new_array)

    ! Copy the data
    new_array(1:size(old_array)) = old_array

    ! Transfer the allocation to old_array
    call MOVE_ALLOC (FROM=new_array, TO=old_array)

    ! new_array is now deallocated

    return
    end subroutine resize

End Program Arrays_0
```

Sample output:

```
 Enter the number (From 1 to Br_gra):
12
 Allocated new array of size            4
The number of iteration is: 3
The result of calculation is: 23
Size of vals is: 4
      7      3     19
      3      1     22
      1      0     23
```